# The only subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ and complete (with the restricted metric) is $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

The only subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ and complete (with the restricted metric) is $\mathbb{R}$.

My work-

Let $A$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ and is complete. Let, $f : \mathbb{R}\to A$ be a homeomorphism. Since $A$ is complete, so it is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ which implies $f(A)$ is closed in $A$. Therefore, $f(A)$ is complete. Then, I want to prove that $f(A)=A$. I am stuck here. If I can prove this then it will easily show that $A^c=\emptyset$ as $f$ is bijective.

Thank you!

Comment: Idea: If you assume $A$ to be minimal (w.r.t inclusion) complete subset homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ then this may work.

Comment: @Sheve That's indeed a nice idea! I fail to see why such a minimal subspace exists though. To use Zorn's lemma, if we pick a chain of subspaces, what would be a lower bound here? If we apply the usual technique of taking the intersection, I can see that it is complete, but I fail to see that it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$. How do you prove the existence of $A$ minimal?

Comment: Also one has to prove that $f(A)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ya.. this would be equivalent to proving the theorem by taking $f$ over and over again.

Comment: @Gae.S. $A\subset\mathbb R$ thus $f(A)\subset A$. Nothing in what he did clearly shows that $f(A)=A$.

Comment: @Sheve yup you're right!

Comment: @Scientifica Oh, I see. Sorry.

Comment: Is this statement true for $\mathbb{R}^n$ as well? This makes your method of proof (if it works out as a correct proof) to be stronger then the ones offered here below. In general I think it is interesting to give new proofs of fundamental and non trivial facts such as "$\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$ iff $n=m$".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$, with the induced metric, is a complete subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, then it is closed. Since $A$ is by assumption is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, it is an interval. A closed interval is of one of the following types:

1. $[a,b]$
2. $(-\infty,b]$
3. $[a,\infty)$
4. $(-\infty,\infty)$

Types 1, 2 and 3 are not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, because removing a point from $\mathbb{R}$ leaves a disconnected set.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to help continue your proof, but here's a different method:

Let $A$ be such a subspace. Since $\mathbb R$ is connected, so is $A$. Therefore $A$ is an interval of $\mathbb R$. To conclude, it's enough to show that $A$ is unbounded.

Assume that $A$ is bounded above. As a subset of $\mathbb R$, it has a least upper bound $s:=\sup A$. There does exist a sequence of $A$ that converges to $s$. Such a sequence would be a Cauchy sequence of $A$ and, if $s\notin A$, then that Cauchy sequence would have no limit in $A$, contradicting its completeness. Therefore $s\in A$ which shows that $A$ is an interval of the form $[y,s]$ or $(y,s]$ (in the second case, $y$ may be $-\infty$). In both cases, $A\backslash\{s\}$ is a connected space, while removing a point from $\mathbb R$ disconnects it. Therefore $A$ is not bounded above. Similarly, $A$ is not bounded below.

**Edit:** As 伽罗瓦 pointed out in comments, one can make the argument shorter: $A$ being complete, it is closed. Therefore $\sup A,\inf A\in A$.

When everything's rightly reformulated, one gets a nice compact proof as in egreg's answer.

Comment: Of course, similarly, $A$ must be unbounded from below as well.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yup. Didn't bother to write it out of laziness (actually I started typing "Simila" then said naaaah), but indeed, for the sake of coherence, I should at least point-out to it. Thank you for pointing that out! I'll type it.

Comment: Can't you just say $A$ will be compact if bounded?

Comment: @Scientifica You have a typo, you mean "therefore $s\in A$", right? Also, you are using the fact that $A \cong \mathbb{R} \iff A\setminus{\{s\}}\cong \mathbb{R}\setminus \{s\}$ where you have proved that the latter can't happen, since $A\setminus{\{s\}}$ is connected and $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{s\}$ isn't. Am I right?

Comment: @伽罗瓦 If $A$ is bounded, we still have to show that it is closed. But indeed we can say it: if $A$ is bounded, applying the above remarks about sup and inf, $A$ must be a closed bounded interval and therefore compact.

Comment: He literally uses the fact that $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: @bing-nagata-smirnov You're right, thank you for pointing that out! As for the second point, that's correct. More precisely: if $f:A\to \mathbb R$ is a homeomorphism, then $A\backslash\{s\}\cong\mathbb R\backslash\{f(s)\}$, but it's np as for any $x,y\in\mathbb R$, we have $\mathbb R\backslash\{x\}\cong\mathbb R\backslash\{y\}$.

Comment: @伽罗瓦 Yup you're right, noticing that $A$ is closed being complete makes the argument shorter. I'll edit it.

Comment: @Scientifica Yes, my bad, I should write $A\backslash\{s\}\cong\mathbb R\backslash\{f(s)\}$. Thank you for the correction and for your reply to my questions, you were very helpful!

Comment: It's a pleasure! Thank you for your comment as well!

Answer (score 0):

Let $d$ be the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$
be a homeomorphism such that $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space.
We go to show that $X=\mathbb{R}$.

Recall that connectedness is preserved by continuous map, so $X=f[\mathbb{R}]$
is connected and hence $X$ must be an interval (Well-known fact:
A subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ is connected iff it is an interval.).
Denote $X=\langle a,b\rangle$, where $\langle$ may be $($ or $[$,
$\rangle$ may be $)$ or $]$ and $-\infty\leq a\leq b\leq\infty$.
Clearly, by considering cardinality, we must have $a<b$. We go to
prove the following facts:

(a) If $a\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\langle$ must be $[$. For, if $\langle$
is $($, Choose $x_{0}\in(a,b\rangle$. Define $x_{n}=a+\frac{1}{n}(x_{0}-a)$.
Clearly, $(x_{n})$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$. However $(x_{n})$
does not converge to any point in $X$, contradicting to the completeness
of $(X,d)$.

(b) Similarly, if $b\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\rangle$ must be $]$.

(c) If $a\in\mathbb{R}$, it will lead to a contradiction for the
following reason: Suppose that $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $X=[a,b\rangle$.
Since $f$ is bijective, there exists $x_{1}\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$f(x_{1})=a$. Choose $x_{0},x_{2}\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x_{0}<x_{1}<x_{2}$.
Since $f$ is injective, $f(x_{0})\neq f(x_{1})$ and $f(x_{2})\neq f(x_{1})$.
That is, $f(x_{0})>a$ and $f(x_{2})>a$. Choose $l$ such that $a<l<\min(f(x_{1}),f(x_{2}))$.
Note that $l\in X$ because $X$ is an interval. By intermediate value
theorem (by regarding $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as a continuous
function), there exists $\xi\in(x_{0},x_{1})$ and $\eta\in(x_{1},x_{2})$
such that $f(\xi)=l$ and $f(\eta)=l$. This contradicts to the fact
that $f$ is injective.

(c) If $b\in\mathbb{R}$, it will lead to a contradiction for similar
reason.

(d) By the above discussion, we must have $a=-\infty$ and $b=\infty$.
That is, $X=\mathbb{R}$.